# C#: Declaring and Using XNA Vectors for Matrix Multiplication, et. al

Tags: c#, image-processing, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to declare and use XNA Vectors for Matrix Multiplication, Summation, etc. in C#.

Those will be used for Image processing to make it faster than regular SetPixel and GetPixel. However, I am always failing to find a working example and I tried many examples online but it seems I am missing something.

Any help and sample code?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but there should be a built-in Matrix class that you could use.

Comment: I am trying to facilitate the GPU to get faster image processing capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are worried about Performance then you can revert to coding in  `unsafe` context.

By marking a type, type member, or statement block with the unsafe keyword, you're permitted to use pointer types and perform C++ style pointer operations on memory within that scope, and to be able to do this within the managed execution framework. Unsafe code can run faster than a corresponding safe implementation.

Here is a nice, short example that comes from the book C# 4.0 in a Nutshell:

```
unsafe void BlueFilter (int[,] bitmap)
  {
    int length = bitmap.Length;
    fixed (int* b=bitmap)
    {
        int* p=b;
        for (int i=0, i<length; i++)
        *p++ &= 0xFF;
    }
   }
```

(*[Source](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/0e731437-6baa-4046-9ad8-b8b2b087e3b3/image-manipulation-with-unsafe-code-in-c.aspx)*)

---

Apart from that you should also take a look at this SO Question

[Why is matrix multiplication in .NET so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229442/why-is-matrix-multiplication-in-net-so-slow)

Comment: Thanks. But what about utilitizing the GPU?

Comment: @johnshaddad | You cant directly Utilize GPU as their vendors don't provide a Managed API and nither they have x86/x64 based instruction sets,  NVIDIA Provides CUDA but it only supports C++. So Though You can build an Interop Layer but using Parallelism Would be Lot  Simpler :)

Comment: Oops lol but what about processing HD images in real-time? As in a video in HD that I would like to process live (eg. flipping the photo or doing anything else)? Any pointers to what works best for such cases, possibly with tutorial or sample code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Verctors are just 1 x n matrices. Create a Matrix class, with methods for summation and multiplication.

```
public class Matrix
{
    private int[,] m_array;

    public Matrix(int m, int n)
    {
        m_array = new int[m, n];
    }

    public Matrix(int[,] other)
    {
        m_array = other;
    }

    public Matrix Mult(Matrix other)
    {
        if (this.m_array.GetLength(1) != other.m_array.GetLength(0))
            return null;

        int[,] res = new int[this.m_array.GetLength(0), other.m_array.GetLength(1)];

        for (int i = 0; i < this.m_array.GetLength(0); ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < other.m_array.GetLength(1); ++j)
            {
                int s = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < this.m_array.GetLength(1); ++k)
                    s += this.m_array[i, k] * other.m_array[k, j];
                res[i, j] = s;
            }

        return new Matrix(res);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But what about utilitizing the GPU?